# starting a class file with java.exe and arguments is not working

Tags: java

I'm using a program called glslDevil, which is suppose to hook onto a program to listen to openGL calls.

To set up glslDevil, you need to give it the program, and the program arguments. Java is special, it can't run on it's own. So, I tried giving it the JVM and using arguments to run my java application.

In the program location I put:

C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/java.exe

In the argument setting I put:

java -cp C:\Users\Bob\Documents\testproj\out\production\testproj\stuff\ GameWindow

GameWindow is the entry point with a main method.

there is also a working directory setting, not sure what it's used for, I kept it blank.

So, the problem is, it's not working. Nothing happens. Is there anything obvious I'm doing wrong?

By the way, the class file is generated by intellij, when you debug...

Comment: If the program and arguments are specified separately, you should leave out the `java` in your arguments.

Comment: @Henry I tried that, no luck.